# How to make my kendo dropdown list readonly?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have a dropdownlist and i need to make it read only when user opens the page.But it needs to be enabled after click on edit icon.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var dataSource  =  $("#dropdownElement").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

To make kendo dropdown read only:

```
dataSource.readonly();
```

To remove read only to kendo dropdown:

```
dataSource.enable(true);
```

Comment: actually the correct way to undo the readonly is, by using the readonly() method with false parameter like this: `dropdownlist.readonly(false)`;

Comment: dataSource.readonly(); function not working with jquery V 3.5.1 js and kendo version #v2015.1.408