# kendo angular combo box read only

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using angular Kendo combo box. I want to make that combo box as read only. I am trying to use the attribute readonly="true". But it is not working. Could anyone suggest what is the attribute for it. Code for the following:

```
<kendo-combobox
    [data]="data"
    [textField]="'desc'"
    [valueField]="'name'"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
    [valuePrimitive]="true"
    (readonly)="true">
 </kendo-combobox>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my kendo dropdown list readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521663/how-to-make-my-kendo-dropdown-list-readonly)

Comment: The solution is in jquery and when I am applying the same atribute in angular it is not working.

Comment: Please post the code you wrote for the ComboBox from the template.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need square brackets instead of parentheses:

`[readonly]="true"`

According to the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-target):

> An element property between enclosing square brackets identifies the target property ... Event binding syntax consists of a target event name within parentheses

The [combobox documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/ComboBoxComponent/#toc-readonly) includes a `readonly` property, so it should work (apologies, I can't currently check it, not having a working angular project).